# Is it possible to edit/customize a Sass file and update CSS automatically in the server?

Tags: html, css, sass, koala

I have developed a website using Sass with the help of Koala software on my local machine. Is it possible to edit/customize the Sass file and update CSS automatically in the server? If the client asked me to change the color theme, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible but here is how you can update both Sass and CSS files easily on the server.

Use **Git**.
Make a repository on Github(Open Source) or bitbucket(Private Repository) according to your need and clone the repository on your local machine and make your changes there which will be compiled with kola. Then commit the sass file and CSS file both to your repository.